# Swift animation/transition like UBER app

Tags: swift, animation, transition

Anyone know how the UBER app does the following animation/transition

1) In the main UBER app there is a menu icon with 3 bars in upper left hand corner, when you pan or drag the message view from the bottom (slowly), the menu icon slowly morphs or turns into an up arrow icon and the background slowly turns in to BLACK.  Is this done programmatically or is this done for you through the animation library?

Answer (score 0):

This is a custom animation that they do when the user grabs the cards at the bottom of the screen.

They probably draw the menu icon themselves and then using the animation library they morph the lines and rotate everything to look like an up arrow.

Raywenderlich has some good tutorials on animations and their animation book is really good.

https://www.raywenderlich.com/173544/ios-animation-tutorial-getting-started-3

Comment: That is quite an extra detailing with no added value. It is interesting that it looks like it is animating frame by frame as you slowly drags the card from the bottom.

Comment: Yeah definitely doesn't add much value, but it's something that users notice. It's fun for the user, developer, and the designer. Improving UX anyway possible is always an add in value even if it's just the little things :)